# Android: WebView keydown event: how to get useful key data

Tags: android, webview, keydown

Does anyone have any experience with contenteditable and keycodes in an (Android) WebView?

I'm writing an Android app using a WebView and need to monitor key events. I'm using jQuery, so I'm using `$(document).on('keydown')`.

Problem is, the event received only contains useful information if it's keyCode 13/'Enter'. Things like backspace, delete, or regular characters (all of which I need to be able to monitor) return a value of 229 and 'Unidentified'.

My debugging output looks like this:

```
e = {"originalEvent":{"isTrusted":true},"type":"keydown","target":{"sizzle1500307408528":{"undefined":{"parentNode":[5,3,true]}}},"currentTarget":{"sizzle1500307408528":{"undefined":{"parentNode":[5,3,true]}}},"timeStamp":5361.655000000001,"jQuery310027283423097243387":true,"delegateTarget":{"location":{"ancestorOrigins":{},"origin":"file://","protocol":"file:","host":"","hostname":"","port":"","search":"","hash":""},"jQuery3100272834230972433871":{"events":{"touchend":[{"type":"touchend","origType":"touchend","guid":1,"selector":".script p","needsContext":false,"namespace":""}],"touchstart":[{"type":"touchstart","origType":"touchstart","guid":2,"selector":".script p","needsContext":false,"namespace":""}],"touchmove":[{"type":"touchmove","origType":"touchmove","guid":3,"selector":".script p","needsContext":false,"namespace":""}],"focusin":[{"type":"focusin","origType":"focus","guid":4,"selector":".script","needsContext":false,"namespace":""}],"focusout":[{"type":"focusout","origType":"blur","guid":5,"selector":".script","needsContext":false,"namespace":""}],"paste":[{"type":"paste","origType":"paste","guid":6,"selector":".script","needsContext":false,"namespace":""}],"selectionchange":[{"type":"selectionchange","origType":"selectionchange","guid":7,"namespace":""}],"input":[{"type":"input","origType":"input","guid":8,"selector":".script","needsContext":false,"namespace":""}],"keydown":[{"type":"keydown","origType":"keydown","guid":9,"selector":".script","needsContext":false,"namespace":""}]},"focusin":1,"focusout":1}},"handleObj":{"type":"keydown","origType":"keydown","guid":9,"selector":".script","needsContext":false,"namespace":""}}

e.keyCode = 229

e.key = Unidentified
```

My presumption is that 229 (or 0xe5) is getting returned because that's the 'Process' keyCode related to IME input ([as per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values)). But regardless I don't see any way to get the key value.

(I'm also curious as to why e.KeyCode and e.keyEvent are values when there is no keyCode or keyEvent in that dump of e. But a question for another day, maybe.)

Comment: Here's a quick JSFiddle that demonstrates it: https://jsfiddle.net/oexq4k21/2/ From a regular browser (i.e., desktop Chrome) it works fine; from Chrome for Android it does not.

Comment: Upon further research it seems this is a well-known (and well-complained about) issue specific to Android Chrome only, as opposed to mobile Safari, etc. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118639 keyCodes don't and won't work on Android Chrome.